What is the position of Lord Śiva in Śuddhadvaita sampradāyas?
I'd like to know what the Śuddhadvaita philosophy has to say about Lord Śiva.

Śri Vaiṣṇavas consider him to be a jīva.
Gaudiyas say he's got his own Śiva tattva and is not Nārāyaṇa but close.

What does Rādhāvallabha Sampradāya (or any other following this darśana) say about his position?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
